# audio-echo project issue when write out data

Tags: android, native

I am working in karaoke android app, this is example:
https://github.com/koseonjae/Karaoke
That base on example of [Google](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/audio-echo), please take a look at this trunk:

```
if(fos == nullptr)
        fos = fopen("/sdcard/recorded_audio.pcm", "wb");
      fwrite(buf->buf_, 1, buf->size_, fos);
```

This trunk of code about work on my device S7 Samsung, but crash in other device, so I change it to save **buf** to vector and write out when recording stoped:

```
bool EngineService(void *ctx, uint32_t msg, void *data) {
  assert(ctx == &engine);
  switch (msg) {
    case ENGINE_SERVICE_MSG_RETRIEVE_DUMP_BUFS: {
      *(static_cast<uint32_t *>(data)) = dbgEngineGetBufCount();
      break;
    }
    case ENGINE_SERVICE_MSG_RECORDED_AUDIO_AVAILABLE: {
      // adding audio delay effect
      sample_buf *buf = static_cast<sample_buf *>(data);
      assert(engine.fastPathFramesPerBuf_ ==
             buf->size_ / engine.sampleChannels_ / (engine.bitsPerSample_ / 8));
      engine.delayEffect_->process(reinterpret_cast<int16_t *>(buf->buf_),
                                   engine.fastPathFramesPerBuf_);

      // TODO error crash in some device that has low speed sdcard -> using vector for save data
      /*if(fos == nullptr)
        fos = fopen("/sdcard/recorded_audio.pcm", "wb");
      fwrite(buf->buf_, 1, buf->size_, fos);*/


      sample_buf output = sample_buf();
      output.buf_ = new uint8_t();
      *output.buf_ = *buf->buf_;
      output.size_ = buf->size_;
      bucket.push_back(output);



      break;
    }
    default:
      assert(false);
      return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

In stop function **stopPlay(JNIEnv *env, jclass type)** - I added:

```
if(fos == nullptr)
        fos = fopen("/sdcard/recorded_audio.pcm", "wb");
  LOGE("====stopPlay %u", bucket.size());
  for(auto const& value: bucket) {
    fwrite(value.buf_, 1, value.size_, fos);
  }
  fclose(fos);
  fos = nullptr;
```

I don't know why the fwrite which write directly to sdcard work in EngineService but when My Vector bucket write out ok, but I cannot hear anything - just beep beep sound...
Does someone explane it? Something wrong here?
P/S: I think write to memory like vector is faster than sdcard? It true, isn't it? But not working

Comment: It seems that you do not understand the basic memory structures being used here. This is apparent starting on this line: `output.buf_ = new uint8_t()`. I recommend you do some reading on [dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management#DYNAMIC), and study the definition and usage of the `sample_buf` type within the code base. Use it the way the library authors use it. Take careful note of what happens to the memory pointed at by `buf->buf_` after `EngineService()` returns; make sure you understand its scope/lilfetime.

Comment: I using memcpy instead of copy value of pointer buf->buf_, OR: create and vector to push directly poiter buf into it, but allway is not work.

Comment: If you want to post your new code: edit your question, ping me, and I will take a look at it.

Comment: I temporarily fixed it by resize buffer of I/O fwrite, the crashs are decrease:
char buffer[100663296];
if(fos == nullptr){
        fos = fopen("/sdcard/recorded_audio.pcm", "wb");
        setvbuf(fos, buffer, _IOFBF, 33554432);
}